# ECDiffieHellmanCng PublicKey always the same?

Tags: c#, cryptography

I'm playing around with the C# ECDiffieHellmanCng class and found a (in my opinion strange) behavior using the code from the [sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng(v=vs.100).aspx):
Every generated public key in any project ist the same! Is this correct and a desired behavior?

Example:

```
using (ECDiffieHellmanCng bob = new ECDiffieHellmanCng())
            {
                bob.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
                bob.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
                Trace.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bob.PublicKey.ToByteArray()));
            }
```

The trace will always have "ECK5B" as output. Using a different constructor will only differ the output a bit but not the fact, that it is always the same.
Do I missunderstand something and this result is as expected and there is no chance to provide a random public key? 
I just thought the system would use some more randomness.

Comment: Binary data cannot usually be converted to a UTF-8 encoded string. Have you tried Base64 or Hex instead?

Comment: My fault. Before converting to UTF-8 I've compared the first bytes of the public keys and they where the same - but you are right. Converting to Base64 shows different keys after the 13th digit. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ToByteArray()` method, returns the (Windows-specific) [CNG blob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375520(v=vs.85).aspx) describing the key.

The blob layout is

```
UINT32 Magic
UINT32 cbKey
<cbKey bytes of public key>
```

the value for `BCRYPT_ECDH_PUBLIC_P521_MAGIC` is `0x354B4345`, which if viewed in Little-Endian order (`45 43 4B 35`) is the ASCII string `ECK5`. The `x` coordinate of a point on the NIST P-521 curve needs up to 521 bits, or ((521+7)/8) == 66 bytes. `(UINT32)66` in Little-Endian is `42 00 00 00`. So all of the byte arrays (for a NIST P-521-based public key) will start with

```
45 43 4B 35 42 00 00 00
```

(and then have 66 more bytes of the X component of the ECPoint).  Since the ASCII string will terminate when it reads the first `0x00`, this gets interpreted (as a string) as `ECK5B`.

As you've already discovered, this value isn't actually a string, so in order to be treated as one it needs to be encoded to a string-safe format, such as hex or Base64.  Since hex is a 1=>2 encoding (or 1=>~3 with spaces) and Base64 is a 3=>4 encoding, most applications end up using Base64.