# Import ECC key - CngKey.Import() - Parameter is incorrect

Tags: c#, jwt, x509certificate, ecdsa

**Purpose** : Generate a **ES256** signed **JWT** using [jose-jwt](https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt)

**Steps:**

1.Generate a **private key** and **certificate** using openssl:

```
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey > privateKey.pem
openssl req -new -key privateKey.pem -x509 -nodes -days 365 -out public.cer
```

2.Token generation:

```
var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
   { "sub", "mr.x@contoso.com" },
   { "exp", 1300819380   }
};
var certificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("public.cer");
byte[] publicKey = certificate.GetPublicKey(); //public key has 65 bytes

//Below step is throwing an error:
var cng = CngKey.Import(publicKey, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
var token = JWT.Encode(claims, cng, JwsAlgorithm.ES256);
```

**CngKey.Import()** is throwing "**The parameter is incorrect**" error while trying to generate a **CngKey** required for the **Jose.JWT.Encode** function. Not sure what step I am missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make the **CngKey import** working with help from the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762380/importing-ecc-based-certificate-from-the-windows-certificate-store-into-cngkey).

Now `Jose.JWT.Encode()` was throwing "Unable to sign" error at the following line:

```
return JWT.Encode(claims, cng, JwsAlgorithm.ES256)
```

And I ended up writing my own implementation of private key signing using **.NET 4.6** `GetECDsaPrivateKey()`.

You can see my **final solution** on the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129214/c-sharp-jwt-load-es256-pem-file-into-cngkey-jose-jwt/42985435#42985435)

Public key needs to be modified by *discarding the first byte*, leaving 64 bytes, then prefix with *4 bytes for curve* and *4 bytes for key length*. Here is the complete solution:

```
var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
   { "sub", "mr.x@contoso.com" },
   { "exp", 1300819380     }
};
var certificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("public.cer");
byte[] publicKey = certificate.GetPublicKey(); //public key has 65 bytes

//Discard the first byte (it is always 0X04 for ECDSA public key)
publicKey = publicKey.Skip(1).ToArray();:

//Generate 4 bytes for curve and 4 bytes for key length [ 69(E), 67(C), 83(S), 49(1), 32(Key length), 0, 0, 0 ]
byte[] x = { 69, 67, 83, 49, 32, 0, 0, 0 };    

//Prefix above generated array to existing public key array
publicKey = x.Concat(publicKey).ToArray();

var cng = CngKey.Import(publicKey, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob); //This works
return JWT.Encode(claims, cng, JwsAlgorithm.ES256); //Fixed, see my final solution link above
```

Answer (score 2):

The "ECCPUBLICBLOB" format isn't the same as the "public key" field from the certificate.

The format of the ECCPUBLICBLOB is explained in [another question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42676205/6535399), but here's a quick summary:

```
UINT32 Magic
UINT32 cbKey
<cbKey bytes of public key>
```

The value for `Magic` will depend on which curve and algorithm you're trying to import (some hints at https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/System/Security/Cryptography/BCryptNative.cs,fde0749a0a5f70d8,references).

`cbKey` is how many bytes are in the public key.

The public key bytes will be a bit different than what you get from `GetPublicKey()`.  It'll be just the curve X coordinate, which will be (for NIST P-256) bytes 1..33  (the first byte of `GetPublicKey()` will be 0x04, which says that the payload is uncompressed, then 32 bytes of the X coordinate, then 32 bytes of the Y coordinate).

```
IEnumerable<byte> blobBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(0x31534345);
blobBytes = blobBytes.Append(BitConverter.GetBytes(32));
blobBytes = blobBytes.Append(cert.GetPublicKey().Skip(1).Take(32));

byte[] eccblob = blobBytes.ToArray();
```

System.Linq extension methods used for brevity.

Though, if you just need an object instance, `cert.GetECDsaPublicKey()` should do the right thing for you (each call to that returns a new instance, so manage the lifetime appropriately)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was partially close to what I was looking for. Also `cert.GetECDsaPublicKey()` is not available in .NET 4.5